# How to add conditional buttons using Bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to make something where by default the "Add" button on the right of the field is disabled, and if I select "+ Add" from the left dropdown, the "Add" button becomes active, and if I select "- Reduce" from the same dropdown, the reduce button will replace Add button on the right of the field.

The +Add and -Reduce options are available by clicking on the chevron on the left of the field.

Can someone help please?

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.1.0/css/all.css">


<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6 float-left">
    <p>Funds (Add/Reduce)</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6 mb-3 pl-0 float-left ac-set">
    <div class="input-group add-reduce-div">
      <div class="input-group-prepend">
        <div class="dropdown">
          <button class="btn btn-dropdown dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"></button>
          <div class="dropdown-menu add-reduce" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#"><i class="fas fa-plus funds-icons"></i>&nbsp; Add</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#"><i class="fas fa-minus funds-icons"></i>&nbsp; Reduce</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <input type="number" class="form-control universal-input add-reduce-input">
      <div class="input-group-append">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-dropdown" disabled="disabled">Add</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @MiXT4PE the error is still there after your edit. Therefore I added the Fiddle

Comment: Why would it work? You just created a dropdown menu with buttons. How are they tied to the input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you think of something like this?

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $(".a-plus").on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var thisBtn = $(".add-reduce-input + .input-group-append .btn");
    thisBtn.attr('disabled', false);
    thisBtn.text('Add');
    thisBtn.addClass('btn-add');
    thisBtn.removeClass('btn-reduce');
  });
  $(".a-reduce").on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var thisBtn = $(".add-reduce-input + .input-group-append .btn");
    thisBtn.attr('disabled', false);
    thisBtn.text('Reduce');
    thisBtn.addClass('btn-reduce');
    thisBtn.removeClass('btn-add');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.1.0/css/all.css">


<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6 float-left">
    <p>Funds (Add/Reduce)</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6 mb-3 pl-0 float-left ac-set">
    <div class="input-group add-reduce-div">
      <div class="input-group-prepend">
        <div class="dropdown">
          <button class="btn btn-dropdown dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"></button>
          <div class="dropdown-menu add-reduce" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
            <a class="dropdown-item a-plus" href="#"><i class="fas fa-plus funds-icons"></i>&nbsp; Add</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item a-reduce" href="#"><i class="fas fa-minus funds-icons"></i>&nbsp; Reduce</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <input type="number" class="form-control universal-input add-reduce-input">
      <div class="input-group-append">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-dropdown" disabled>Add</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The code that does the action required was missing.